# android app crashed while initiating lopoj AsyncHttpClient in Main activity

Tags: java, android, androidhttpclient, loopj

I need to get some data from external server in an android app.
for that i use

```
com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9
```

But my app crashed while initiating client in MainActivity

```
private MyClient client;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   client = new MyCLient();
}
```

Then, if I run the app, it crashes. except new MyCLient() app is ok.

MyClient.java

```
package com.example.hellow;

import com.loopj.android.http.*;

 public class MyClient {

private static final String BASE_URL = "https://httpbin.org/";

private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

public static void get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
      client.get(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
  }

  public static void post(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
      client.post(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
  }

  private static String getAbsoluteUrl(String relativeUrl) {
      return BASE_URL + relativeUrl;
  }

}
```

Comment: Error file link:  [link](http://pastebin.com/HC7vayG0)

Comment: i tried with okhttp3. result is same.

after calling 

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Comment: Please post your log.

Comment: [Log file link : pastebin](http://pastebin.com/HC7vayG0)

Comment: Please Check whether the library is at perfect address-
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.hellow-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]